# Где должен находиться static class не связанный ни с Models, ни с ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю MVVM. Перебрав несколько тулкитов, остановился на [SimpleMVVM](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com)

С самим тулкитом в его базовой основе вроде бы разобрался, но встал вопрос. Есть приложение - сканирует файлы определенного типа в заданном каталоге, считывает из каждого описание и создает соответствующий xml-файл. Потом из этого xml-файла делается выборка по нужным параметрам и выводится на экран. На данный момент сканирование каталога сделано в виде static class с двумя методами:

```
public static class Scaner
{
    public static int NewScan() {...};
    public static int Rescan() {...};
}
```

В дальнейшем планируется создать еще один похожий static class - конвертор из одного формата в другой.

Собстенно вопрос: а где должны находиться эти два класса, если они не относятся ни к Models, ни к ViewModels (по крайней мере насколько я понимаю), и как их правильно вызывать?

Answer (score 1):

Если проект маленький, можете расположить этот класс рядом с теми классом(-ами), где он используется. Если проект большой, то, как правило, он разбивается на части согласно области (например, `UI`, `TextProcessing`, `ImageProcessing` и т.д.), поэтому можете вынести в отдельный подпроектик (`Scanning`).